# sigmoid関数を使用するとエラーが起きる

Tags: python, python3

現在、Deep learningを勉強していまして、昨日までは下記のコードで実行してもエラーが起きなかったのですが、先ほど勉強を始めようと思い、PC起動⇒下記のコードを実行したところ、なぜかエラーが起きてしまいました。なぜ、昨日までは実行できて、いきなり実行できなくなってしまったのか理解できません。
この下記の現象についてご教示願います。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import numpy as np

def init_network():
    network = {}
    network['W1'] = np.array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.5], [0.2, 0.4, 0.6]])
    network['b1'] = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
    network['W2'] = np.array([[0.1, 0.4], [0.2, 0.5], [0.3, 0.6]])
    network['b2'] = np.array([0.1, 0.2])
    network['W3'] = np.array([[0.1, 0.3], [0.2, 0.4]])
    network['b3'] = np.array([0.1, 0.2])
    
    return network

def forward(network, x):
    W1, W2, W3 = network['W1'], network['W2'], network['W3']
    b1, b2, b3 = network['b1'], network['b2'], network['b3']
    
    a1 = np.dot(x, W1) + b1
    z1 = sigmoid(a1)
    a2 = np.dot(z1, W2) + b2
    z2 = sigmoid(a2)
    a3 = np.dot(z2, W3) + b3
    y = identity_function(a3)
    
    return y

network = init_network()
x = np.array([1.0, 0.5])
y = forward(network, x)
print(y)
```

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-d459db580be1> in <module>
     27 network = init_network()
     28 x = np.array([1.0, 0.5])
---> 29 y = forward(network, x)
     30 print(y)

<ipython-input-61-d459db580be1> in forward(network, x)
     17 
     18     a1 = np.dot(x, W1) + b1
---> 19     z1 = sigmoid(a1)
     20     a2 = np.dot(z1, W2) + b2
     21     z2 = sigmoid(a2)

NameError: name 'sigmoid' is not defined
```

Comment: 質問のプログラムを動かす前に`sigmoid`という関数を定義して使っていて、インタプリタやコンソール等を終了しないまま質問のプログラムを継続して実行したのでは？ 前日までに何をやっていたか思い出すとか、あるいはこの辺を参考に、質問のプログラムに`sigmoid`関数を追加してみてはどうでしょう？ [Pythonでシグモイド関数](https://qiita.com/nkkt/items/491e34824c6193e38b1b), [【Python】シグモイド関数 / 複雑な関数定義](https://qiita.com/Cesaroshun/items/90a5677e0718983904c0)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

コメントを参考にして、再度確認してみます。

Answer (score 1):

出力の感じからすると Jupyter Notebook の python カーネルを使ってらっしゃるのではないでしょうか。とすると、「昨日」は何らかのセルを実行した際に sigmoid 関数を定義していて使えていたものの削除されており、「今日」はそれらの状態がリセットされており、改めてセルを先頭から実行しようとしたところ定義が見つからずエラーになっているように見えます。

Jupyter Notebook は（特別に再実行しない限り）今まで実行したセルによって変更された状態を引き継ぎます。このため見た目のプログラムは同じでもセル内容の変更や削除によって初期状態が異なると結果が異なることがありえます。

もし質問文に記載されているプログラムが今回の notebook の全体なのでしたら、まずは sigmoid 関数を定義してみてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
jupyter labの方をしています。

上記の内容ですが、sigmoid関数の定義方法がよくわからなく、何をimportしたら使えるでしょうか？

お手数おかけしますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: sigmoid は普通に自分で定義するか適当なライブラリのものを使うかするだけですね……。そもそもご自身で一度定義されていたような挙動をしているのでそのときのものをご利用になれば良さそうです。

Comment: コメント通りに、一度定義したコードを利用したところ、問題なく実装できました。ご丁寧にありがとうございます。