# pythonのエラーについて TypeError: ufunc 'kv' not supported

Tags: python, sympy, scipy

Pythonに慣れておらず、エラー内容と解決方法がわからない。
これは呼び出したkvが積分に対応していないということですか？

**ソースコード**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.special
from scipy.special import kv
from sympy import *
from scipy.integrate import quad

z = Symbol('z')
v = 5/3
y = quad(f(v,z), (z,x, np.inf))
F = x*y
plot((F),(x,0,10),title='test',xlabel='x',ylabel='F')
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8f89c7044d48> in <module>
      9 z = Symbol('z')
     10 v = 5/3
---> 11 y = quad(f(v,z), (z,x, np.inf))
     12 F = x*y
     13 plot((F),(x,0,10),title='test',xlabel='x',ylabel='F')

TypeError: ufunc 'kv' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: もう少し前提条件等を追記してください。OSの種類/版数,Python版数,Anaconda/Jupyter/GoogleColab等環境、そして参照している資料があればURLや出典といった情報を書いておくと回答や助言が得られ易いでしょう。ちなみにWindowsの素のPython3.8.5だと`NameError: name 'f' is not defined`という別のエラーになりました。

Comment: 例えばこの記事 [sigmoid関数を使用するとエラーが起きる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/68510/26370) のように以前に実行した何かの影響が残っていて逆に問題が発生したかも？と言ったことも考えられます。

Comment: 失礼しました。環境はwindowsのWSLでAnacondaを通して、jupyter notebookで書いております。NameError: name 'f' is not definedについてはご指摘通り過去の定義が残ったままでした。

Answer (score 2):

sympy と scipy ライブラリを区別してください。sympy は記号計算のためのライブラリであり、scipy ライブラリは数値計算のためのライブラリです。それぞれでは内部で用いられるアルゴリズムが違います。基本的に素のままでは共存はできないと思ってください。

今回のプログラムはおそらく Jypter Notebook 系のソフトウェア上で実行されており、質問文にあるプログラムも不完全なものになっています。特に、関数 `f` が定義されていません。しかし実行結果を見るに `f` の評価には成功しているようです。おそらく別のセルで定義されたか、一度定義されたものを削除した後リセットしていないのでしょう。

エラー `ufunc 'kv' not supported for the input types` はおそらくこの関数 `f` の定義に関係して生じています。`f` の定義の中で関数 `kv` をお使いではないですか？　import 文を見るにおそらくこの `kv` は `scipy.special.kv` なのでしょう。具体的な数値が引数に渡されることが期待されている関数に sympy の記号計算に使われるデータを渡しているため、「対応していない型の値が引数に渡されたよ」というエラーが出ているように見えます。

積分の記号計算をなさりたいのでしたら、まずは sympy の積分に関するドキュメントを読むのは如何でしょうか: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html。また `f` の内容によっては `sympy.lambdify` などの関数が役に立つかもしれません: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html。

そうではなくて積分の数値計算をなさりたいのでしたら scipy ライブラリの積分に関するドキュメントに載っている実装例が助けになるかもしれません: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html。

Comment: scipyの積分ドキュメントから実行できたのですが、変数のxのエラーがimport numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as special
y = integrate.quad(lambda z: special.kv(5/3,z),x,np.inf)
F=x*y
plot((F),(x,0,10),title='test',xlabel='x',ylabel='F')-------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-54b8e47f52c7> in <module>
      5 
----> 6 y = integrate.quad(lambda z: special.kv(5/3,z),x,np.inf)
      7 F=x*y
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: scipy をお使いなのであれば数値計算ですので、積分範囲に不定の変数を使うことはできません。

Comment: 最終的には横軸ｘ縦軸F=ｘ*ｙでのプロットがしたいのですが、ｘの範囲、刻み幅指定をしても無理でしょうか？

Comment: 更に matplotlib の [plot のドキュメント](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)か、[plot のチュートリアル](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html)をご覧いただくのが良さそうです。matplotlib でのグラフ描画に必要なのは f(x) の値のリストです。関数 f とその引数の範囲ではありません。